# Rig Expert AA-35 ZOOM Amateur Band coverage in the United States

Tags: hf, antenna-analyzer

I am having difficulty understanding the low end of the AA-35 ZOOM frequency range. The tool can help with frequencies between 35 and .06 MHz. Looking at a chart I saw that 60 kHz was Standard Frequency and Time Signal. This area on the frequency charts seems to be below 2,200 Meters.
My question is this; does the AA-35 ZOOM measure below 2,200 Meters? If so, what is the application for United States Amateur Radio users? My understanding is that the AA-35 ZOOM covers 160-10 Meters.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to link to exactly the documentation you're referring to. It's no good if we score the Internet and then come up with something else. And please be clear what you mean with "below": below in frequency, or in wavelengths?

Comment: 60kHz is 5000 meter wavelength, and it is spec'd to work there. It may not do a great job there, perhaps. But then 160m is well within the normal operating range of the instrument.

Comment: I think you answered your question. The Rig Expert covers .06 to 35 MHz and everything in between. 60 KHz = .06 MHz. As mentioned, 60 KHz is roughly equal to 5000 meters of wavelength. The instrument covers most of the commercial AM broadcast band, all the shortwave frequencies, Ham, and CB. A better tool for the job with a much wider bandwidth (up to 6 GHz) and less expensive is a Tina VNA.

Answer (score 4):

60 kHz is about 5000 meters in wave length so yes it does go below 2,200 meters.

The Rig Expert AA-35 is an antenna and cable analyzer. While often used by amateur radio operators, it is not restricted to them. For example it could be used to measure an antenna for commercial AM radio which in the US ranges from 540 Khz to 1700 kHz. It covers a large range of frequencies and impedances. Many of which are not used in amateur radio.